# Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(Ljava/util/zip/ZipInputStream;)V

Tags: java, r, nosuchmethoderror, xlconnect

I have just encountered a new error playing around with XLConnect. 
Running this simple code:

```
PD=matrix("PD",2,2) ; 
library(XLConnect) ; 
writeWorksheetToFile("H:/R/PD.xlsx",PD,sheet="PD",startRow=1,rownames=FALSE,header=TRUE) ; 
writeWorksheetToFile("H:/R/PD.xlsx",PD,sheet="PD",startRow=4,rownames=FALSE,header=FALSE) ;
```

I received

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(Ljava/util/zip/ZipInputStream;)V
```

Once I receive the error message, the file PD.xlsx cannot be edited or moved, until I close R.

Interestingly, running the exact same code on another instance of R, I don't have any error.

Does anyone have some suggestion on how to avoid this error?

I'm using RGui 64-bit version 3.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Run R uder 32-bit version: tools,Global Option,General,Change,tick Use machine 32-bit